# Maya Calendar No Password Prompt for CALDAV

Tags: calendar

I created a new calendar using my CALDAV server information (including full path to the calendar). This works in Thunderbird/Lightening. (I also verified the paths by logging in using Epiphany going directly to the path.)

I create the calendar in Maya. However, I never get an error nor a prompt for a password. The calendar appears in the list of calendars but never syncs.

---

**Update:** I spent several hours on this and see that Maya automatically strips a port from the URL--for example, mycalendarurl.com:2080/calendars/ becomes mycalendarurl.com/calendars/ . I tried the URL less the port via a web browser and the missing port does not allow connection to the CALDAV server.

Answer (score 1):

If you use https connection you need to add your certificate to trusted authorities on your computer:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect mycalendarurl.com:2080     | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/mycalendarurl.crt
cd /tmp
sudo cp mycalendarurl.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mycalendarurl.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Then create your caldav calendar with the caldav link from your server.
After establishing connection, the calendar application will prompt for a password.

Comment: is your solution documented anywhere haven't seen this information around. In your example you have listed "mycalendarurl.com:2080" is this just a default name and port for the local calendar or is it meant to represent something? Having some issues getting calendar to connect to an HTTPS CalDav compliant calendar, any assistance would be greatly appreciated. ""Cheers
G

Comment: mycalendarurl is your own caldav server, it applies, when you use self signed https certificate. If you buy a certificate for your server from certificate authority, then you do not need this solution. Replace mycalendarurl with your own calendar domain. You can google for similar results when you search how to import your self signed certificate into your elementary system.